# How to call class in angular custom pipe

Tags: angular, class, pipe

Hi below is my custom pipe code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
// Here I need to import my another class
@Pipe({ name: 'creativeType' })

export class Creativepipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value:any)
{
   if(value)
   {
      //execution
   }
}
}
```

And am created a separate class there I have declared all my project constants nearly its more than 1000, I need to call my class into custom pipes module, below is my class,

```
export class HouseAd {

public M_IG = "Some Value";
public M_IF = "Some Value";
........
........
........
```

}
I tried with import class and create Instance for that and access that means shows undefined value, Anyone help to solve my problem

Comment: import class in your pipe and redirect use class const variable with "Classname.variableName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are constants, you are better of using an `enum`:

```
export enum HouseAd {
  M_IG = 'Some value',
  // ...
}
```

Which you can then access anywhere if you import it:

```
transform(value:any) {
   if(value === HouseAd.M_IG) {
      //execution
   }
}
```

Comment: @PierreDuc  I used InjectToken concept to inject my constants file so that i can use them in html files also. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: @MayurPatil maybe the injectionToken is the angular way to do it, but it's a big abstraction. The advantage you get with that is that you can easily override the constants using `provide`. If that's not necessary, you can just keep it in an enum file and for access inside html you can use a public property on the component: `public constants = Constants`

Answer (score 0):

In order to inject the class it must be an `Injectable`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // Only available with angular 6+, else add it to providers
})

export class HouseAd {

  public M_IG = "Some Value";
  public M_IF = "Some Value";
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but its not worked for me, If am access variable in the class means show does not exist

Comment: @Thiyagarajan Did you use the injected property rather than the name of the class when trying to access it?